# C++ Benefit of rvalue reference constructors for simple types (Vector3, Matrix, etc)

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

Is there any advantage to using rvalue references if the object being passed does not have complex data? For example, would the following have any advantages over just using references?

```
class Vector3
{
public:
    float X, Y, Z;

    Vector3(const Vector2& vector2, float z)
        : X(vector2.X), Y(vector2.Y), Z(z)
    {

    }

    // Is this any better than the above?
    Vector3(Vector2&& vector2, float z)
        : X(std::move(vector2.X), Y(std::move(vector2.Y), Z(z)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the example you give will not have any benefit. For basic numeric types such as `float` moving and copying are effectively the same operation.